# how to make facebook graph api curl request in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, curl

From facebook graph api docs this is curl request i need to make. From console its working. Now I want to move this post in delayed job. How can I do this:

```
 curl -F 'access_token=xxxxxxxxx' \
  -F 'photo=http://xxxxxx.com/photos/13' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/my_app_namespace:upload'
```

PS: I have token etc everything. I just want to code this curl request in ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quick and dirty, just send the command to the shell with tics or `system`.

For a more elegant and efficient (having native bindings) solution, use *[curb](http://rubygems.org/gems/curb/)* Ruby gem.

> Curb (probably CUrl-RuBy or something) provides Ruby-language bindings for the libcurl(3), a
>   fully-featured client-side URL transfer library. cURL and libcurl live
>   at http://curl.haxx.se/ .

Answer (score 1):

[`Net::HTTP`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) should be all you need for a simple request like this